# Get app that is consuming web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How do I extract/get the URL name that is consuming my web service?

For say, i have a .asmx web service, consumed by .aspx web app, in my .asmx code, i need to get that web app's url? Is that any way doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to inspect the HTTP request.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

Comment: Thanks, i will mark it as answer, but will this get me the IP address or the URL ie. 200.100.150.120 or http://www.sharp.com?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url - i got it.

Comment: -1 This is not reliable. Among other things, what if something other than a web page makes the call. In fact, I don't believe this will be set if the service is called from the codebehind.

Comment: @John Saunders - The OP specifically stated: "...need to get that web app's url".  He stated a web application is making the request, in which case the referrer header in the HTTP request should be populated.

Comment: No, it won't be, if it is called from codebehind, or if the browser doesn't feel like it. Referrer is not reliable since it is not mandatory that it be filled in, or that it be filled in "correctly".